# Compare dataframe cell value with series then find sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let say I have Pandas DataFrame as shown (df_All);

```
  Category Count
0  Apple     1
1   Pen      3
2  Orange    4
3   Book     1
```

and 2 Pandas Series like this (df_Fruit, df_Object);

```
  Fruit                                Object
0 Apple                              0 Pen
1 Orange                             1 Book
```

I want to compare to the DataFrame to the Series so that i will get sum like this table;

```
  Category Count
0 Fruit      5
1 Object     4
```

What I have try is to use loop function and compare as follow;

```
def getCategoryCount(row):
    food_count = 0

    for value in df_Fruit['Fruit']:
        if row['Category'] == value:
            food_count = row['Count']

    return food_count

df = df_All.apply(getCategoryCount, axis=1)
```

However df fill like this;

```
0 1
1 0
2 4
3 0
```

I can use `df.sum()` to get the value but only for Series at a time since if i put another for loop in `getCategoryCount` it will sum the whole df.

If possible I want `getCategoryCount` return as Pandas DataFrame

Comment: i like Wen approach on this question even though I dont get the sum I want, but i have to Nde Samuel Mbah for best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first group the categories into 2 lists as follows:

```
fruits = list(fruits)
objects = list(objects)
```

Then I would slice `df_all` and sum the `Count` column resulting in `df` defined as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Fruits', df_all[df_all.Category.isin(fruits)]['Count'].sum()], ['Objects', df_all[df_all.Category.isin(objects)]['Count'].sum()]], columns = ['Category', 'Count'])
```

When I print `df`, the result is:

```
>>> df
    Category    Count
0   Objects      3
1   Fruits       5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` to get the `groupby` key

```
s=pd.concat([df1,df2]).stack()

df.groupby(df.Category.map(dict(zip(s,s.index.get_level_values(1))))).Count.sum()
Out[232]: 
Category
Fruit     5
Object    4
Name: Count, dtype: int64
```

Comment: you mean df1 = df_Fruit, df2 = df_Object?

Comment: @Fahmieyz yep :-)

Comment: I try the code you send but when check df = pd.DataFrame(df_All['Category'].map(dict(zip(s,s.index.get_level_values(1))))) it missing the count